# Create Kurento RTP Receiver in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, rtp, kurento, kurento-media-server

I am trying to create Kurento RTP receiver in node.js.

I'm using the below github repo for the reference:

[kurento-rtpendpoint](https://github.com/givo/kurento-rtpendpoint)

The example given on Kurento's website is in Java [kurento-rtp-receiver](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/tree/master/kurento-rtp-receiver).

My requirement is to create **RTP Receiver in Node.JS.** Finding no help on the internet.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Your question is too generic to get attention. You should specify what is your specific goal and if possible include some code snippet of what you had done and where you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the Kurento repository, I hope it helps you

[Kurento tutorial for Node.js](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node)

Comment: According to "[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)", provide some context for your link to explain why you included it.